# Google music player restores deleted playlist

Tags: music-player, google-play-music

Why does my Google music player automatically create some of the playlists I deleted before?

When I delete a playlist, the playlist appears again after I turn off my Nexus 7 and turn it on again. It doesn't happen to all playlists, only specific ones.

Comment: Are you syncing Google Music with, say, iTunes? If you delete a playlist (or a track) from Google Music without also deleting it from iTunes it'll get re-sync'd.

Answer (score 1):

Try to clear data and cache.

**Settings**-->**Apps**-->*select* **Google player***(click on it)*-->**clear data&cache**

and just **turn off  sync with Google Play music**( this may be the cause of your issue).

Comment: I tried, did not work

Comment: When I clear data&cache the playlist created by automatically disappears for a while but after a while it appears again and the cache and data go back to their previous numbers

Comment: Answer edited..That playlist may be in your Google account. When you delete all data&cache and then it sync again. Just turn off sync option in Settings-->google-->uncheck Play music